# How to increase the rate of absorption and assimilation of food?

Tags: digestion, bile

i was reading [this](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_time_required_for_human_digestion)
and want to know

excerpt from the above link`Thus, the time for food to travel from one end to the other probably ranges from about 20 to 30 hours`
I believe it's 24 hours for a normal person going for poop every morning, But I was curoius if anybody could increase the rate of absorption making my digestive and defacaeting system better performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate of absorption is controlled by two essential physical factors:

1. Contact **surface** between intestinal content and intestinal mucosa.
2. **Time** of contact.

There are many other factors including intestinal peristalsis, gastric, pancreatic and bile secretions that stimulate/help absorption.

So increasing or accelerating intestinal passage of food won't do any good (see [diarrhea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diarrhea)). Water will not be absorbed into the blood flow thus leading to dehydration and hypovolemia. Also the alimentary principles, vitamins, essential aminoacids won't be absorbed.

On the other hand, slowing down the passage has negative effects. It allows bacterial saprophytic flora to multiply so much that those microorganisms become pathogenic by producing toxins. And increased contact time equals increased absorption both of toxins and food principles.

Comment: OOps! i was totally wrong